# Conditionally render table with select options in React & MUI

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I'm trying to conditionally render table information in a table that needs to be reusable. Essentially if the data coming in has status property (data.status), that column needs to be rendered with a dropdown that displays the current status and has the other options selectable.

This what I have so far:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-rgb-fm5k20

Comment: Which column needs to be conditionally rendered?

Comment: @ChetanAciduniform16Kondawle the status column. should be the last column in the table

Comment: Can you also add sample Columns data and row data. Its unclear why u need to map columns in Table body

Comment: @ChetanAciduniform16Kondawle i think all that is doing is making sure the data is linked to the correct column. im not 100% sure how its working, if im being honest. but i will add some sample data and columns to the main post if it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally render it like this. Again I dont think you need to use column map in your table body. Since your data will be 2d array you can map each of its elements like this.

```
const selectValues = [
  { value: "1", label: "One" },
  { value: "2", label: "Two" },
  { value: "3", label: "Threee" },
];

function RenderSelect(props) {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={props.cell}
        >
          {selectValues.map((value) => (
            <MenuItem value={value.value}>{value.label}</MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}

export function AppTableM(props) {
  const { dataList, columns } = props;

  return (
    <main>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {columns.map((column, i) => (
                <TableCell key={i}>{column.field}</TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>

          <TableBody>
            {dataList.map((data, i) => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={i}>
                  {data.map((cell, i) => {
                    if (i == data.length - 1) {
                      return (
                        <TableCell key={i} component="th" scope="row">
                          <RenderSelect value={cell} />
                        </TableCell>
                      );
                    } else {
                      return (
                        <TableCell key={i} component="th" scope="row">
                          {cell}
                        </TableCell>
                      );
                    }
                  })}
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </main>
  );
}
```

**After Question Update**

Filter out the value of columns and then map it.
I have also added onemore state `hasStatus` for the sake of simplicity

```
export default function TableComponent() {
  const [dataWithStatus] = useState<DataType[]>(withStatus);
  const [dataNoStatus] = useState<DataType[]>(noStatus);
  const [data, setData] = useState<DataType[]>([]);
  const [hasStatus, setHasStatus] = useState<boolean>(
    dataWithStatus[0].hasOwnProperty("status")
  ); //Change dataWithStatus to dataNoStatus to change data


  // add a bang infront of false: ( !false ) to toggle between data with and without status
  const [withData] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // let isMounted = false;

    // if (!isMounted)
    setData(hasStatus ? dataWithStatus : dataNoStatus);

    // return () => {
    //   isMounted = true;
    // };
  }, [withData, dataWithStatus, dataNoStatus, data]);

  return (
    <div>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {columns
                .filter((col) =>
                  hasStatus ? col.value : col.value !== "status"
                )
                .map((column: any, i: number) => (
                  <CellHeader key={i}>{column.field}</CellHeader>
                ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>

          <TableBody>
            {data.map(({ status, ...datum }: any, i: number) => {
              return (
                <StyledRow key={i}>
                  {columns
                    .filter((col) =>
                      hasStatus ? col.value : col.value !== "status"
                    )
                    .map((column: any, i: number) => (
                      <TableCell key={i} component="th" scope="row">
                        {column.value !== "status" ? (
                          datum[column.value]
                        ) : (
                          <RenderSelect status={status} />
                        )}
                      </TableCell>
                    ))}
                </StyledRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );
```

Also removed `selected` prop from `<option>` as it was resulting in error on console and set `defaultValue` instead

```
function RenderSelect(props: SelectProps) {
  const { status } = props;

  return (
    <select
      style={{
        minWidth: "130px",
        border: "none",
        backgroundColor: "transparent"
      }}
      defaultValue={status}
    >
      <option value="water">Water</option>
      <option value="coffee">Coffee</option>
      <option value="icedTea">Iced Tea</option>
    </select>
  );
```

Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-benz-riws2q)

Comment: ive been messing with this and think im getting close but i dont think its supposed to do what i need it it to do. 

instead of having 4 separate components for 4 separate tables, im trying to do it all in one component and ill do my best to elaborate a bit more.

the table should be something like
firstname | lastname | age | ...etc 

but if the data coming in has a value called status (data.status) it should adjust the table like this:

firstname | lastname | age | ...etc | status

and render the correct data in each column.

Comment: If you can tell how your data is going to look like and columns is going to look like maybe then it will be more clear. Right now structure of both `data` and `column` from props `const { data, columns } = props` is unclear. Please provide data or create a codesandbox for same

Comment: hello, im not good with code candbox but i believe this is the name of it: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-rgb-fm5k20

Comment: Hope it works for you

Comment: worked great,  really appreciate it!